# equal height for 2 column layout but different height on each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use js to make 2 column to have equal height. The left column is users' input, so it's dynamic, some time it has more content or less. My problem is I have many rows instead of one. I thinking of using each() to loop through and apply to each row, but my class name on markup is the same.

```
boxes = $('.heightHack'); maxHeight = Math.max.apply( Math, boxes.map(function() { return $(this).height(); }).get()); boxes.height(maxHeight);
```

demo http://bootply.com/105122

Comment: Are your rows in a table or something? could you post your html of at least 2 rows?

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado sorry I forgot the demo. updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrapping it on a loop and using `.find()`:

```
$(".container").each(function(){
   boxes = $(this).find('.heightHack');
   maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
     Math, boxes.map(function() {
       return $(this).height();
   }).get());
   boxes.height(maxHeight);
});
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/105123

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Exactly, loops on all the elements that match the selector. MOre info here: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: one problem is I can't see instant result when I'm dragging and resizing the windows, I have to refresh, why?